# Big image inside ScrollView won't let scroll

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I'm trying to add an Image (by the image full size) into a `ScrollView` component, the idea is to let the image be on it's own size (without limiting it) but instead to let scroll horizontal and vertical (depend on the Image).
so I'm using `Image.getSize()` for it inside a `ScrollView`, here is my component,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      width: 10,
      height: 10,
      image: 'http://www.francedimanche.fr/parole/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Angelina-Jolie.png',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Image.getSize(this.state.image, (width, height) => {
      this.setState({ width, height });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <Image
          style={{ width: this.state.width, height: this.state.height }}
          source={{uri: this.state.image}}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go horizontal *or* vertical in a ScrollView.  To get both you can just nest them:

```
  <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
    <ScrollView>
      <Image
        style={{ width: this.state.width, height: this.state.height }}
        source={{uri: this.state.image}}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  </ScrollView>
```